# Facebook does not call webhook (real time updates) when a user is invited to an event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates, facebook-events

I'm subscribing to Facebook real time updates for events. I was expecting Facebook to call the webhook when a user is invited to an event as well as when a user creates a new event.

But the webhook is only getting called when a user creates an event.

Is it possible to be notified on webhook when a user is invited to an event?

Comment: No, that’s not possible, because the `user/events` edge only covers their _reply_ to the invitation.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe. Is polling the only solution? (I want a list of all the events a user has created or has been invited to.)